# Upload files with different attributes in Yii2 ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii2  ActiveForm with two form field that accepts file input.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'mainImage')->fileInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'productImage[]')->fileInput() ?>
```

In the controller i have:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();
    $model->supplier_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

    $imageArray = ['mainImage','productImage'];
    $mainImageIndex = 1;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->mainImage = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'mainImage');
        $model->images = $model->singleImageUpload();
        //UploadedFile::reset();

        // var_dump($model->mainImage);
        // exit();

        $model->productImage = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'productImage');
        $images = $model->multipleImageUpload();
        $imageCount = count($images);




        if ($model->validate() && $model->save(false)) { 

            for ($i=0; $i < $imageCount; $i++) { 
                $imageModel = new ProductImage();
                $imageModel->product_id = $model->id;
                $imageModel->image = $images[$i];
                $imageModel->save();
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

        }

    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In the Model class, I have these validations rules:

```
[['mainImage','productImage'], 'safe'],
[['mainImage','productImage'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'jpeg, jpg, png','checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false, 'maxFiles'=>10],
```

Every time i submit the form I get an error of `mainImage` field stating `Please upload a file.`  There is no error for `productImage`
What could be the possible fix for this?

**Edit**
Images for `mainImage`and `productImage` are successfully uploaded though the validation error persists on for the `mainImage`

Comment: show complete code for the `controller/action`, the 2 lines you posted dont help much

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have added the code for the controller

Comment: are you sure that you havent added the file fields in the required rule ? and have you checked if the other `productImage` that has multiple file uploads is working? and both the fields are declared on top of your model ?

Comment: I checked, `mainImage` and `productImage` are not in required uless and have been declared at the top of the model

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload multiple files then you needed to change your view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'mainImage')->fileInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'productImage[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
```

And your `rule` in `model` says that you have been trying to upload multiple image for attributes `productImage[]` and `mainImage`. But view says that attribute `mainImage` used for single file so change the rule.

```
[['mainImage'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'jpeg, jpg, png'],
[['productImage'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'jpeg, jpg, png','checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false, 'maxFiles'=>10],
```

In controller,

```
$model->productImage = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'productImage');
$model->mainImage = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'mainImage');

if ($model->multipleImageUpload()) {
   // file is uploaded successfully
   return;
}
```

In your model,

```
public function multipleImageUpload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) { 
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For more reference please go through this link: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload

Comment: the problem is about uploading `mainImage` and `productImage` at the same time not uploading multiple files for `productImage`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was validation in the model class.
I had marked them as `safe`

```
[['mainImage','productImage'], 'safe'],
```

I commented out this validation and it worked